# PySerial and Arduino not communicating correctly

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I want the Arduino to send information to the python script only when the Arduino receives the correct command from the python script. There seems to be a miscommunication somewhere.

Arduino code:

```
char inChar;
bool serial_ready;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  while (Serial.available()) {
    // read the incoming byte:
    inChar = Serial.read();
    if (inChar == 'r') {
      Serial.print('L');
    } else {
      Serial.print(inChar);
    }
    serial_ready = false;
  }
}
```

Python script:

```
import serial

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ser = serial.Serial('COM4',115200,timeout=0)
    # send signal to arduino
    ser.reset_input_buffer()
    ser.reset_output_buffer()
    try:
        ser.write(b'r')
        while (ser.inWaiting() <= 0):
            print('waiting')
        byte_wait = ser.inWaiting()
        ard_in = ser.read(byte_wait)
        print(ard_in)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('KeyboardInterrupt')
    ser.close()
```

Sometimes I get `b'\xf0'` after a few `waiting` are printed out (which is not what I'm looking for) and sometimes it gets stuck in the loop and just prints `waiting` until I stop it. Why does it return `b'\xf0'` instead of `L` or `r`? Why does it sometimes not return anything?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding a repeated `Serial.println("Test")` to the Arduino loop to make sure the link is ok?

Comment: I just tried it and it prints `Test\n` over and over again. The link is okay.

Comment: What if you do the opposite? Send 'a' to the Arduino and get it to flash an LED (pin 13 is handy) if it reads 'a'

Answer (score 0):

Here a test with the onboard LED and a flushing the buffer (works only if you are not hammering data from the phyton side);

```
// Open a serial connection and flash LED when input is received
int ledRed = 13;      // Onboard LED connected to digital pin 13
char inChar;
bool serial_ready;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledRed, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  while (Serial.available()) {
    // read the incoming byte:
    digitalWrite(ledRed, HIGH);
    inChar = Serial.read();
    if (inChar == 'r') {
      Serial.print('L');
    } else {
      Serial.print(inChar);
    }
    digitalWrite(ledRed, LOW);
    Serial.flush();
  }
}
```